# Create user table name with hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I would like to create an object in MS SQL with hibernate, name of this table is "user". it does not work!. 
I think this problem may caused by name of table/entity, user is keyword. 
what should I do to have table with name "user"?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User  {
```

Comment: Call the table `Users`, since it is going to store a set of users, and in addition this will not conflict with a reserved word? I understand that in the entity model the thing is a user, but you need to draw a line between the app and the schema somewhere.

Comment: @Reimeus that's because you're looking at MySQL documentation. The question is about SQL Server. [Try here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should use grave accent (`). for use keyword in hibernate we have to use (`) around keyword.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`user`")
public class CompanyUser extends
```

Comment: It didn't work with oracle,Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

Comment: In Oracle and JPA 2.0 it works with double qouts. for ex: @Table(name="\"user\"")

Answer (score 5):

Enclose the table name in square braces:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "[user]")
public class User  {
```

That way Hibernate will escape it when it creates the table. If you put all your field and table names in square braces as a rule, you never have to consider the underlying DBMS when setting up your mappings.

<rant>It always bothered me that you had to do this. One of the major goals of Hibernate is to isolate your code from the underlying database -- I never understood why the dialect implementations don't properly handle escaping reserved keywords.</rant>

See also: [Using database reserved keywords in Hibernate](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-use-database-reserved-keyword-in-hibernate/)